# Dynamic method chain?

Tags: ruby

How can I call a nested hash of methods names on an object?

For example, given the following hash:

```
hash = {:a => {:b => {:c => :d}}}
```

I would like to create a method that, given the above hash, does the equivalent of the following:

```
object.send(:a).send(:b).send(:c).send(:d)
```

The idea is that I need to get a specific attribute from an unknown association (unknown to this method, but known to the programmer).

I would like to be able to specify a method chain to retrieve that attribute in the form of a nested hash. For example:

```
hash = {:manufacturer => {:addresses => {:first => :postal_code}}}
car.execute_method_hash(hash)
=> 90210
```

Comment: What you wrote as "the following chain" is not a chain. It is a hash.

Comment: Your code will work as is. The question is not clear.

Comment: Is this something particularly about Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Your last example is incomplete. What is `car`? What is `execute_method_hash`? And what makes it return `90210`? It is not helpful.

Comment: execute_method_hash is the method i would like to create. given a hash, this method will traverse through the hash subsequently calling each method on the result of the previous method call.

car is just an example of an object which belongs to a manufacturer. executing this method chain will get the first address of that manufacturer and return its postal code, which is 90210

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use an array instead of a hash, because a hash allows inconsistencies (what if there is more than one key in a (sub)hash?).

```
object = Thing.new
object.call_methods [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

Using an array, the following works:

```
# This is just a dummy class to allow introspection into what's happening
# Every method call returns self and puts the methods name.
class Thing
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts m
    self
  end
end

# extend Object to introduce the call_methods method
class Object
  def call_methods(methods)
    methods.inject(self) do |obj, method|
      obj.send method
    end
  end
end
```

Within `call_methods` we use `inject` in the array of symbols, so that we send every symbol to the result of the method execution that was returned by the previous method send. The result of the last send is automatically returned by `inject`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much simpler way.

```
class Object

  def your_method
    attributes = %w(thingy another.sub_thingy such.attribute.many.method.wow)
    object = Object.find(...)
    all_the_things << attributes.map{ |attr| object.send_chain(attr.split('.')) }
  end

  def send_chain(methods)
    methods.inject(self, :try)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined method, but you can define your own method for that:

```
class Object
  def send_chain(chain)
    k = chain.keys.first
    v = chain.fetch(k)
    r = send(k)
    if v.kind_of?(Hash)
      r.send_chain(v)
    else
      r.send(v)
    end
  end
end

class A
  def a
    B.new
  end
end

class B
  def b
    C.new
  end
end

class C
  def c
    D.new
  end
end

class D
  def d
    12345
  end
end

chain = { a: { b: { c: :d } } }
a = A.new
puts a.send_chain(chain)  # 12345
```

Tested with http://ideone.com/mQpQmp